# C++ segmentation fault while counting character occurrences in string

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, c-strings

I've written a simple function to count occurrences of a character in a string. The compiler is fine. However, as I try to run it, it produced a segmentation fault.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// To count the number of occurences of x in p
// p is a С-style null-terminated string
int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
    if (p == nullptr)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // start the counter
    int count = 0;
    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        if (*p == x)
        {
            ++count;
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char myString[] = "Hello";
    cout << count_x(myString, 'l');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By what magic do you believe `p` will turn into a `nullptr`? The loop condition never becomes false - instead, `p` runs off the end of the string and starts accessing random memory addresses, whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Yeah. Change the nullptr to NULL... That could work.

Comment: I don't see how `p` ever changes. Looks like an endless loop to me.

Comment: @RetiredNinja yea...I missed that line. p++. Thank you. How are you recently?

Comment: Your code is broken. Just use the answer provided by Viktor Alkhimov. When dealing with text like things in C++, *always* go to std::string.

Answer (score 2):

There's two mistakes in your code:

1. You only ever look at the first character in the string.
2. The last character of a null terminated string is a null character. You're testing the pointer itself.

Comment: thanks @Bill Lynch, I changed my code into this and it works. 

int count_x(char* p, char x)
{
    if (*p=='\0')
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    //start the counter
    int count=0;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        if (*p==x)
        {
            ++count;
        }
        p++;
    }
    return count;
}

Comment: Not sure if I am crazy or other upvoters are crazy. This is almost the same problem as OP's code. You only increment count when it matches. If the first character doesn't match, it will still loop forever.

Comment: @texasbruce: Yep. It was pretty sad. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use std::string

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     std::string str = "Hello";
     std::cout << std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), 'l');
}
```